# -moz-user-select in Javascript

Tags: javascript

-moz- is the Problem here. -webkit- & -ms- are working:

```
document.body.style[-moz-user-select] = 'none';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2z04sre/1/

Maybe an alternative? Did try it with `'-moz-none'`

Comment: You forgot to quote the identifier: `document.body.style["-moz-user-select"]='none';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use camelcase instead, that seems to work

```
document.body.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2z04sre/7/)

Answer (score 0):

> **`-moz-user-select` Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: **it will not work for every user**. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Take a look at **[user-select Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)** for more informations, you could find an alternative in the following post **[CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)**.

Hope this helps.